# Error when performing rsh command

Tags: remote-debugging, rsh

1. I've tried executing a simple "ls" command on a remote server, using the command:
   **rsh -l limlim/myPassword myServerName "ls"**
   When running this command, I get the following error message:
   **rshd: luser too long**
   --> What am I doing wrong here?
2. My final goal is to use rsh to work on the server files, remotely, as I'm working on the files on my Eclipse, locally.
   -->How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered switching to the modern equivalent of rsh, ssh?

ssh is the standard tool for interacting securely with remote hosts, and you will find that there are more people with knowledge of ssh who are able to help you.